# C++ conditional template type with template functions error

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, boost, boost-geometry

I have such piece of code

```
    namespace bg = boost::geometry;
    typedef typename std::conditional<highDimension,
                                    typename bg::model::point<double, 6, bg::cs::cartesian>,
                                    typename bg::model::point<double, 5, bg::cs::cartesian>>::type point;
    ..........
    point p;                    
    p.set<0>(0);
    p.set<1>(0);
    p.set<2>(0);
    ..........
```

GCC show me a lot of errors like "error: invalid operands of types '' and 'int' to binary   'operator<'
      p.set<1>(col.a());" So it just try to 'compare' `p.set` and `1`

The boost class really has template function set, but compiler don't use it as function.

If i make typedef directly from boost type, like `typedef bg::model::point<double, 5, bg::cs::cartesian> point;` everything works fine.

I just want to select different dimension sizes depending on template argument `highDimension`. But now I have no idea how to force GCC understand me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `highDimension` is a template argument, `point` becomes a dependent type, so you need to write `template` here:

```
p.template set<0>(0);
```

As to why you need `template` there, read the answer here:

- [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

---

BTW, you don't need `typename` in the arguments:

```
typedef typename std::conditional<highDimension,
                 bg::model::point<double, 6, bg::cs::cartesian>,
                 bg::model::point<double, 5, bg::cs::cartesian>>::type point;
```

You could also use `using`:

```
using point = typename std::conditional<highDimension,
                 bg::model::point<double, 6, bg::cs::cartesian>,
                 bg::model::point<double, 5, bg::cs::cartesian>>::type;
```

This looks better from readability point of view (IMHO).

Or you could simply write this:

```
using point = bg::model::point<double, highDimension?6:5, bg::cs::cartesian>;
```

Looks even better.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works as expected.

Comment: +1 For C++11 type alias. Is thousands of times more readable than old `typedef`.

Comment: Can you please point me where i can read about this `p.template set<0>(0);` construction

Comment: @johngull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Comment: @johngull: Sure! Edited the answer with an awesome link.